# Calculating the amplitude for a free particle to propagate from $\mathbf{x_0}$ to $\mathbf{x}$ in nonrelativistic case

Tags: quantum-mechanics, propagator

I am reading the Peskin & Schroeder *An introduction to quantum field theory,* p.14 and some question arises.

In their book p.13~14, they calculated $U(t)=\langle\mathbf{x}|e^{-iHt}|\mathbf{x_0}\rangle$ for $E=\frac{\mathbf{p}^{2}}{2m}$ (nonrelativistic case) as follows:

$$U(t)=\langle\mathbf{x}|e^{-i(\mathbf{p}^{2}/2m)t}|\mathbf{x_0}\rangle
= \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^{3}} \langle\mathbf{x}|e^{-i(\mathbf{p}^{2}/2m)t}|\mathbf{p}\rangle\langle\mathbf{p}|\mathbf{x_0}\rangle 
 = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3}}\int d^{3}p e^{-i(\mathbf{p}^{2}/2m)t} \cdot e^{i\mathbf{p}\cdot (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x_0})} = (\frac{m}{2\pi i t})^{3/2} e^{im(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x_0})^{2}/2t}.$$

My question is, why the third and final equality true? Can anyone present more detailed derivation?

C.f. Original image is as follows:

[image]

Comment: [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#n-dimensional_with_linear_term)

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask more question? In the Gaussian integral you linked( n-dimensional with linear term ; is it really the formula you intended? ) , what the matrix $A$ and $B$ will be?   And, still, why the third equality is true? I truly want to understand these derivations.

Comment: Are you asking why $f(\hat{\mathbf{p}})|\mathbf{p}\rangle=\mathbf{p}|\mathbf{p}\rangle$? Yes, you have three-dimensional integral here ($n=3$.)

Comment: Uhm..literally, I'm asking that, in the above image, why the third and fourth equality is true. For the fourth equality, can we use the Gaussian integral formula? If so, how? ~~

Comment: I can't post an answer here, since we are dealing with basic QM and basic math here (homework level answers are not allowed in this community.) You might be jumping too far ahead by trying to study Peskin's book.

Comment: O.K. Thanks.~~ Now for me these are not basics. It seems that multidimensional integral does not appear well in Q.M. book. I think that I am unfamilier to multidimensional integral :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are using the usual normalisation of eigenstates of momentum and position:

$$ \langle\mathbf{p}|\mathbf{x}\rangle  = e^{-i\mathbf{p}\cdot \mathbf{x}}, \hspace{3 mm }  \langle\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{p}\rangle  = e^{i\mathbf{p}\cdot \mathbf{x}}$$

Moreover, the operator $e^{-i(\mathbf{p}^{2}/2m)t}$ is already written in the basis of momenta, so

$$ \langle\mathbf{x}|e^{-i(\mathbf{p}^{2}/2m)t}|\mathbf{p}\rangle=e^{-i(\mathbf{p}^{2}/2m)t}\langle\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{p}\rangle=e^{-i(\mathbf{p}^{2}/2m)t} e^{i\mathbf{p}\cdot \mathbf{x}}$$

Hence

$$ \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^{3}} \langle\mathbf{x}|e^{-i(\mathbf{p}^{2}/2m)t}|\mathbf{p}\rangle\langle\mathbf{p}|\mathbf{x_0}\rangle 
 = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3}}\int d^{3}p e^{-i(\mathbf{p}^{2}/2m)t} \cdot e^{i\mathbf{p}\cdot (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x_0})} $$

Since $\mathbf{p}^2=p_x^2+p_y^2+p_z^2$, you have a product of three integrals:

$$ \int dp_x e^{-i(p_x^{2}/2m)t} \cdot e^{ip_y\cdot (x-x_0)}\int dp_y e^{-i(p_y^{2}/2m)t} \cdot e^{ip_y\cdot (y-y_0)}\int dp_z e^{-i(p_z^{2}/2m)t} \cdot e^{ip_z\cdot (z-z_0)}$$

Each of them is a Gaussian integral, so you can apply the formula

$$ \int du \,e^{-au^2+bu}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{\frac{b^2}{4a} }$$

three times with $ a= it/2m$, $b=i(x-x_0)$, (and $b=i(y-y_0 )$ etc.)

Comment: Wow, I got it. Thakns for kind explanation. Your calculation answer will be helpful for a long time for me ~ :)